# Free Windows Forms Components Similar to jQuery UI Draggables

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, components

**EDIT:**

So, I ended up making my own *basic* solution to this problem, and it can be found in my own answer to the question below. [Or, here's a link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579412/windows-forms-components-similar-to-jquery-ui-draggables/1591964#1591964)

**Original Post**

I'm doing some UI programming for a small .NET application. The application has some collections of items that need to be displayed in a grid sort of format (X columns by Y rows) and the grid elements need to be able to get dragged around to different grid locations, and possibly out of the grid all together.

The most comparable sort of UI design elements I can think of are the [jQueryUI Draggables](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).

Do I have to roll my own or are there components people have already written to act like this? Even better, are there any *free* components? Or is there an easy way to do this that I just don't know about (don't do a lot of .NET UI programming..)

Also these "grid items" need to be able to include windows form components. The [DataRepeater](http://blogs.msdn.com/vsdata/archive/2009/08/12/datarepeater-control-for-windows-forms.aspx) control is *close* to what I need, except it only supports horizontal or vertical alignments, not grids of items.

Here's a visual example of what I'm looking for:

[image: Awesome Grid Layout UI]

I tried to stick with a halloween theme here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I rolled my own solution and hosted it on GoogleCode:

[draggableitemorderedpanel- A .NET Winforms Component... Kinda like jQuery UI Draggables (not really, maybe someday)](http://code.google.com/p/draggableitemorderedpanel/)

here's a screenshot:

[image: Actual Gameplay!!!]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://draggableitemorderedpanel.googlecode.com/files/example1.png))</sub>

and another just resized:

[image: More actual gameplay!!]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://draggableitemorderedpanel.googlecode.com/files/example2.PNG))</sub>

Hope this helps someone else out. Also it's super basic and pretty sucks right now but gets the job done.

Anyone that wants project access can have it.

Answer (score 0):

The System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel control supports dragging and dropping, you just have to handle the right events.  You could make your own "GridItem" user control, with the icon, caption, background color, etc displayed on a Panel, and then plop a bunch of them in the tablelayoutpanel, and wire up some event handlers. Here's something similar:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/1cade626-b76d-40c5-9e5a-101cf2a5e412

Comment: I started writing some custom components, but I might give that a shot as my base. I have FlowablePanel, which automatically orders its child controls based on their width and height, which I had planned to inherit to DragabbleFlowablePanel, that will allow the controls to be moved around from inside.

Comment: Hey, FlowLayoutPanel already exists but doesn't suit my purposes. I reinvented a wheel!